# Problems hosting a .NET service using a service reference created using SvcUtil.exe: XmlSerializer errors on Wrapped mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, xml-serialization

My problem is the following:

- Here http://www.opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/ I use VS2010 in order to create a service reference. I create it with no problems.
- I want to implement the service interface creating a service of mine. So I implement the `Service` interface.
- I create a svc file:

  ```
  <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
              Debug="true" 
              Service="Full name of the class 
              (the class implementing the Service interface)" %>
  ```

OK, I got this:

> XmlSerializer attribute 
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in LocaleID.
>   Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and XmlAnyElement attributes
>   are supported when IsWrapped is true.

Let me point the following:
Do not ask me for Web.config file, whether it has a service model configuration settings or not, it is not different, the same problem persists.

What's the problem?

I've been wondering around to solve this, I would like to note that, in the past, someone else used wsdl.exe in order to create an asp.net service reference that uses `WebService` and `WebMethod` as service attributes, that approach does not lead to this error.
But I would like to use WCF...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the OPC DA specification. I switched to the old-style .NET Webservices (web reference instead of service reference). The .NET webservices do accept the WSDL specification of the OPC foundation.

These are the steps I took to create such a proxy:

1. Create a .NET **v2** project.
2. Add a Web reference to http://www.opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0
3. Adjust the project settings, so it compiles for .NET v4 again.
4. Use the proxies.

It's not an ideal solution, but it's beats creating your own wrapper.